# Swift 3 - How to compare UIImage width and height?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I needed to compare the width and the height of the UIImage, when width is larger than height, I will add border. Below is my code on a cocoa touch class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let x = p2Image.image?.size.width
    let y = p2Image.image?.size.height


    if x > y{
        p2Border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black


    }else{

        p2Border.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    }
}
```

It prompt error Binary operator > cannot apply to two CGFloats operand, please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` are optionals due to *optional chaining*, so you need to unwrap them.  *Optional binding* is a safe way to do that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    if let x = p2Image.image?.size.width,
       let y = p2Image.image?.size.height {

        if x > y {
            p2Border.backgroundColor = .black                
        } else {                
            p2Border.backgroundColor = .clear                
        }
    }
}
```

This will safely do nothing if `p2Image.image` is `nil`.

---

If you want to assign `.clear` when `p2Image.image` is `nil`, then you can combine the *optional binding* with the `x > y` comparison like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    if let x = p2Image.image?.size.width,
       let y = p2Image.image?.size.height,
       x > y {

        p2Border.backgroundColor = .black
    } else {
        p2Border.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying! There's no error with your method, but it doesn't work..

Comment: It sounds like `p2Image.image` is `nil`.  How is that being set?  Update your question to show how `p2Image.image` is set.

Comment: No, it is not nil, I saved the image with **UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "keyImage")**. Then, every time I launch the app, I use **let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "keyImage") as! NSData**, follow by **myImage.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)**

Comment: By default, the border is black, currently I'm using a portrait image, but it shows black border

Comment: When are you doing this?  Does it happen after `viewDidLoad` runs?

Comment: For saving the image, I use a button action. For loading image I use viewWillAppear().

Comment: `viewWillAppear` happens after `viewDidLoad`, so why don't you move the code above into `viewWillAppear` after you load the image?

Comment: Well, I just tried to put the method into my button action and viewWillAppear(), it works!

Comment: Actually you don't have enough rep to upvote, but you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark to make it green.